# C++ While loop scoping issue

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, scope

I recently started learning C++, and I'm currently trying build a tool that I recently built in python. My issue is that I can't figure out how I can make the length of the list of words global for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ....
        fstream file;
        file.open(argv[i], ios::in);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            string tp;
            while (getline(file, tp)) {
                // cout << tp << "\n" << endl;
                string words[] = {tp};
                int word_count = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);
                for (int e = 0; e < word_count; e++) {
                    cout << word_count[e];
                }
            }
            file.close();
            } else {
                cout << "E: File / Directory " << argv[i] << " Does not exist";
                return 0;
            }
    ....
}
```

Where it says `int word_count = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);` and `tring words[] = {tp};`, I want to be able to use that globaly so that I can then later use then length of the array and the array itself later on so that I can loop through it and use them in another statement.

Can someone tell me how to do so?
And by the way, I've only been doing C++ for about 4 days so please dont get annoyed if I don't understand what you tell me.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using arrays rather than a C++ [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of strings? They will resize for you so you don't have to specify the size of an array.

Comment: Thanks, Just figured that out, but I would also like to be able to go though the through the vector at a later time with a for loop for obtain each item from inside, but this will all be going on in another statement, so I need someway to return the vector. Any idea on how I do that? :? |

Comment: You can just declare a vector `std::vector<std::string> v;`, add to it with `v.push_back(some_string)` and index it in your for loop just like an array: `v[index]`. [This page](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) should have all the examples you need.

Comment: Arrays are second-class citizens. They still follow all of the old C rules from the 1970s. They do not grow. They are hard to copy, and they are generally inferior to a library container that follows modern idioms like what you are used to coming in from Python. `string words[] = {tp};` is an array of one string. Always and forever. Because it is scoped inside the loop, a new one is made on every iteration of the loop. Basically useless to you. As suggested above, you want a `vector` and it should be defined in the narrowest scope that encompasses all of the places you wish to use it.

Comment: Side note: If your compiler is relatively up-to-date you can replace `int word_count = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);` with `int word_count = std::size(words);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string words[] = {tp};` creates an array with one element in it, the whole line. The name `words` implies that you instead want to store the individual words. The scope is also wrong if you want to use it after the loop is done. You need to declare it before the loop. Use a `std::vector<std::string>` to store the words. It could look like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    // ...
    if (file) {

        std::string word;

        while (file >> word) {     // read one word
            words.push_back(word); // store it in the vector<string>
        }

        std::cout << "word count: " << words.size() << '\n';

        // print all the words in the vector:
        for(std::string& word : words) {
            std::cout << word << '\n';
        }

        // file.close() // not needed, it'll close automatically when it goes out of scope
    }
```

Comment: This work for me and I'm happy it does, but could you also explain how I would use it with words.size() in another statement: https://pastebin.com/RbgC5isW

Comment: @bobross You can use the `vector<string>` like an array if you want `words[0]` will be the first word. `words[1]` will be the second word etc. You can also call functions that accepts a `std::vector<std::string>&` to effectively use it in other parts of your program. If you want to use it in an even bigger scope (like your pastebin suggests) you need to declare the vector outside that bigger scope. I think you should put it at the start of the `main` function if I read the pastebin-code correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to c++, what do you mean I can use std::vector<std::string>& in a function, Since really, I want to be able to use it in another part of the callable arguments

Comment: @bobross I updated my comment above. I've updated the answer too and moved the `words` declaration to the start of `main`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It works just fine now .

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues here.  First, rather than adding `tp` to an array called `words` on each iteration of the loop, you're actually creating a new array `words` and assigning `tp` to the first element of the array. `words` is destroyed at the end of each iteration of the while loop, but even if it wasn't, the `{tp}` expression would overwrite whatever was already in the array. Your line to calculate the length will therefore always calculate the length as 1.

Next, `word_count[e]` is trying to read element `e` of an array called `word_count`, but `word_count` is actually an integer. I'd be surprised if this actually compiled.

First I'd recommend you use a `std::vector`, and then if you just increase its scope to outside the loop then you can use it elsewhere. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        fstream file;
        file.open(argv[i], ios::in);
        std::vector<std::string> words;
        if (file.is_open()) {
            string tp;
            while (getline(file, tp)) {
                words.push_back(tp); // Add tp to the vector of words
            }
            int word_count = words.size(); // vectors 'know' their own size.
            for (int e = 0; e < word_count; e++) {
                    cout << words[e];
            }
            file.close();
            } else {
                cout << "E: File / Directory " << argv[i] << " Does not exist";
                return 0;
            }
        }
        // You can now use words as you please, because it is still in scope.
}
```